# How an incoming in-page html link can be displayed at the top of the page?

Tags: html, wordpress, url, hyperlink

Consider the following:

Page A has a link

```
http://example.com/page#design
```

Page B is on `example.com`, has name `page`, and has an element

```
<h2 id="design">Design</h2>
```

I expected that clicking on the link on page A, the browser would display the `h2` element on the top of the page.

In my case it does not, neither in Firefox nor in Chrome.

What else should I tell in my html to achieve the desired result?

Comment: That's strange. It should definitely scroll to that element.

Comment: I am using Wordpress. Should it cause this behaviour?

Comment: Not by itself, no. But maybe your theme has some JS for a “smooth scroll” functionality, and that’s not working correctly ... or something like that. But rather impossible to tell without seeing the whole thing in action.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with Wordpress. Wordpress does not use the standard way to create in-page links with simply `id` attributes but one has to use anchors and `name` attributes:

```
<a name="design"><h2>Design</h2></a>
```

Now it works.

This page helped clarifying this problem:

https://www.kasareviews.com/wordpress-page-jump-links/

Comment: For some reasons, it works in Firefox but not in Chrome. I'll go to Wordpress Stack Exchange to figure out this.